# Installed Git via homebrew on OSX , man file problems, other potential problems?

Tags: macos, osx-lion, git, homebrew, man

I installed Git via homebrew, on OSX 10.8, with an already existing version of Git. The new version wouldn't show up, so I renamed the old git files (git, gitk etc...)in `/usr/bin` , to `*-old`. Now the new git shows up, but the man files still belong to the old git version.

The new git installed via homebrew is located in `/usr/local/bin/git` and its man files are in `/usr/local/Cellar/` for some reason. Some of the other packages I have installed via homebrew such as autoconf seem to have been picked up by man while others have not, such as `apple-gcc42`, and `git`.

**Question:** How do I override the old git man files and replace them with the new ones?

**Question 2:** are there any other dependencies OSX that I should be aware of that could be broken by changing the file like this?

Answer (score 4):

First, make sure `/usr/local/bin` appears before `/usr/bin` in your `PATH` variable.

```
$ echo $PATH
```

If not, add the following to your `.bash_profile` (you probably don't need to, I think `homebrew` does this when you install it):

```
PATH="/usr/local/bin:$PATH"
```

Also in `.bash_profile`, add `/usr/local/Cellar` to `MANPATH`:

```
MANPATH="/usr/local/Cellar:$MANPATH"
```

(Note: it may be a longer path you need to add, like `/usr/local/Cellar/git/1.8/share/man`. Check which directory actually contains the `man1` directory containing the various `git` man pages.)

---

If you still need to see, e.g., an old `git` man page, you can pass a full path to the `man` command:

```
$ man git  # Finds page under /usr/local/Cellar
$ man /usr/share/man/man1/git.1   # Original git man page
```

Comment: It works, I like it very much. I just move the /usr/local/bin to the begin of the $PATH, the man pages change automatically, Mac OS X mountain lion.